# How to remove class after animation is complete?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

your help would be appreciated:

I created this slider with jQuery, which you can see here: [demo url](http://www.room4.co/TEST/contentHub/index2.html)

The back buttons take you back to the start (rewind animation) in case you wanna revisit the steps.

Associated to the rewind animation there's an `.addClass("fadeOut")` given to `.textBox`, so that they fade out.

I would like to get rid of `.fadeOut` once the rewind animation is completed so that the boxes can fade in again when clicking on `.forward`.

I made an attempt with the commented code below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('.forward').click (function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find($(".textBox")).addClass("fadeIn");
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find($(".textBox .forward")).addClass("fadeIn");
    $(this).addClass("fadeOut");
});


$('.moveFluxDouble').click (function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(".flux").animate({"left": "-=66.6666666%"},"slow");
});


$('.moveFlux').click (function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(".flux").animate({"left": "-=33.3333333%"},"slow");
});


$('.moveFluxBack').click (function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(".flux").animate({"left": "0"},"slow");
    $(".forward").removeClass("fadeIn");
    $(".forward").removeClass("fadeOut");
    $(".textBox").removeClass("fadeIn");
    $(".textBox").not(".start .textBox").addClass("fadeOut");

    //.queue( 
        //function() {
        //$(".textBox").not(".start .textBox").removeClass("fadeOut");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this i think is more useful if you use animation with pure css

```
$(".flux").on(
        "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend",
        function() {
            $(".textBox").removeClass('fadeOut');
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved now :
I did use

`setTimeout(function(){
            $(".textBox").removeClass('fadeOut')},1000);`

instead of the .queue commented code (don't pay attention to it !).

Answer (score 0):

`jquery animate` has a handler that can be invoked once the animation completes.

```
  $(".flux").animate({
     left: "-=33.3333333%"
  }, "slow", function() {
    alert("Animation Completed);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animate has a callback function **complete**, that gets invoked once the animation is complete. So, in general you may try like:

```
jQuery("element_id_or_class").animate({
  //css properties
}, 5000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)